# HTML 5 Video Support

Tags: html, web, html5-video

I want users to upload videos & then i want to display them using HTML 5 , but they are not working in Mozilla & Opera & IE , & neither i can convert videos online to different formats , so how do i proceed .

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use an API that handles the rendering for you. I use [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/), and have had great success with it.

In terms of formats to use, there is a good breakdown of what works where here, under Browser and Device support:

http://mediaelementjs.com/

Basically h.264 should be all you need.

Comment: h.264 does not work in Firefox where you need ogg/theora. I presume that, if mediaelementjs only uses h.264, it might use Flash on Firefox but that's not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, I don't believe it does. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @Rob You need a fallback strategy - not all browsers support HTML5 (IE 6-8). h.264 is a nice compromise, and is the format created by many video cameras, making conversion unnecessary in many cases, if you are willing to acceept Flash when neceesary. You can always create versions in any format you want. Add WebM format in addition to h.264 and you have pretty much covered your bases.

Comment: @Rob, Of course - that is clearly shown by the chart I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Did you delete your comment that h.264 works in FF? I responded to that. You keep bringing up Flash but the OP implies he does not want to use Flash.

Comment: @Rob I deleted nothing. I am suggesting a pragmatic approach since not all browsers can handle HTML5 anyway. You are free to differ in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of video converters you can download and install. The one I have the most success with is handbrake though all of them work well. The only problem I ever have is with IE, of course, which handbrake seems to solve...until last night where I had a video converted with handbrake that would not work in IE.

But you must convert the videos to the proper format to work on the web. You should have no problems with any browser after that except, as expected, with IE which seems to need some magic fairy dust that no one seems to have.